# Debugging Delphi Win32 program in VS Code using LLDB

Tags: windows, debugging, delphi, lldb

My goal is to be able to develop for Delphi in VS Code. Since the last addition of DelphiLSP the actual coding, building and running works great. Especially in combination with GitHub Copilot.

The last hurdle is to be able to debug. The Delphi Windows compiler still does not support LLDB natively so we have to think of some workaround. I have been experimenting with GDB, LLDB and WinDbg, and the outcome is that LLDB is the best bet. It is widely supported in the market and Embarcadero is targeting to use LLDB for all their platforms. However, I don't want to wait until they finally come up with something that works.

I have found this great tool [map2pdb](https://bitbucket.org/anders_melander/map2pdb/) to create PDB files from the Delphi MAP files. It modifies the executable in a way that LLDB can run it, but the major issue for now is that LLDB does not give correct callstacks. In LLDB the callstacks always look like:

```
(lldb) thread backtrace 1
  thread #1
    frame #0: 0x7565113c win32u.dll`NtUserWaitMessage + 12
    frame #1: 0x00a605e6 Tester.exe`__dbk_fcall_wrapper + 2927526
    frame #2: 0x00a5f5b8 Tester.exe`__dbk_fcall_wrapper + 2923384
    frame #3: 0x02791c90 Tester.exe`__dbk_fcall_wrapper + 33538640
    frame #4: 0x02791cf7 Tester.exe`__dbk_fcall_wrapper + 33538743
    frame #5: 0x03e092d2 Tester.exe`__dbk_fcall_wrapper + 57096338
    frame #6: 0x03e0931f Tester.exe`__dbk_fcall_wrapper + 57096415
    frame #7: 0x05753071 Tester.exe`Tester + 93
    frame #8: 0x76d07d59 kernel32.dll`BaseThreadInitThunk + 25
    frame #9: 0x779ab74b ntdll.dll`RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 107
    frame #10: 0x779ab6cf ntdll.dll`RtlClearBits + 191
```

So, it continuously refers to `__dbk_fcall_wrapper` instead of the real method. I have tried creating the PDB file using the YAML output from `map2pdb -bind Tester.map` and `llvm-pdbutil yaml2pdb Tester.yaml` (after exporting the YAML using `map2pdb`) and both give the same result.

How to solve this?

PS: GDB always gives the error:

> (No debugging symbols found in Tester.exe)

WinDBG gives correct callstacks using `map2dbg`, but is hardly supported in VS Code and the source code matching does not seem to work in both VS Code and WinDbg GUI itself.